# Falha ao recuperar um item customizado em uma QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

Eu estou tentando recuperar os dados de um QListWidgetItem quando eu clico na lista, porém não estou conseguindo. Eu fiz uma Widget customizado para listar os elementos, porém apesar de eu conseguir visualizar não consigo no evento click recuperar o meu elemento.

Evento click da aplicaçao

```
void Start::on_phonebookList_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{

    // ContactListItem *cItem = (ContactListItem*)item;
    ContactListItem * cItem = (ContactListItem * )ui->contactPhonebookNumberList->itemWidget(item);
    this->contactSelected = cItem->getContact();
    ui->contactPhonebookName->setText( this->contactSelected->name.toLatin1().data());
    const QVector<PhonebookNumber *> list = this->contactSelected->getNumbers();
    for(int i=0;i!=list.size();i++){
        PhonebookNumber * pn =list[i];
        ui->contactPhonebookNumberList->addItem(pn->number.toLatin1().data());
    }
    ui->nav->setCurrentIndex(NavigationTabs::CONTACT);
}
```

Popular a lista

```
void Start::on_Start_onReloadPhonebookListEvent(const PhonebookType & type)
{
    if(this->getCurrentPhonebookType() != type){
        return;
    }
    const QVector <PhonebookContact*> list = Phonebook::getInstance()->getPhoobook(type);

    this->ui->phonebookList->clear();
    for(int i = 0; i!= list.size();i++){
        QListWidgetItem *widgetItem = new QListWidgetItem();
        this->ui->phonebookList->addItem(widgetItem);
        ContactListItem * contactItem  = new ContactListItem();
        contactItem->setContact(list[i]);
        widgetItem->setSizeHint(QSize(contactItem->width(),contactItem->height()));
        this->ui->phonebookList->setItemWidget(widgetItem,contactItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O cast está sendo feito de forma errada e no local errado, para recuperar essa informação [deve se usar o itemWidget, ele retornará o widget que foi criado.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemWidget)

Alterando onde tem:

```
ContactListItem * cItem = (ContactListItem * )ui->contactPhonebookNumberList->itemWidget(item);
```

Para:

```
  ContactListItem *cItem = qobject_cast <ContactListItem *>(item->listWidget()->itemWidget(item));
```

É possível recuperar o conteúdo e usar normalmente.